# Implementing Index in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Public Class IndexableLinkedList(Of T)
  Inherits LinkedList(Of T)

 '??? implement an index 'property' '

End Class
```

Comment: You might want to look at another SO question about [indexed linked lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712952/is-there-a-known-implementation-of-an-indexed-linked-list) before implementing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the information you’re probably (?) looking for is that indexer properties need to be marked as `Default`:

```
Public Default Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As T
    Get
        ' Return something
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As T)
        ' Set something
    End Set
End Property
```

That said, using an indexer in connection with a linked list is probably not a good idea, performance-wise.