# Benefits of "both" arraylist and linkedlist... possible in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, linked-list, complexity-theory

Of course, I know about the performance difference between arraylist and linkedlist. I have run tests myself and seen the huge difference in time and memory for insertion/deletion and iteration between arraylist and linkedlist for a very big list.

(Correct me if i am wrong)We **generally** prefer arraylist over linkedlist because:

1)We practically do iterations more often than insertion/deletion. So we prefer iterations to be faster than insertion/deletion.

2)The memory overhead of linkedlist is much more than arraylist

3)There is NO way in which we can define a list as linkedlist while inserting/deleting in batch, and as arraylist while iterating. It is because arraylist and linkedlist have fundamentally different data-storage techniques.

Am I wrong about the 3rd point [I hope so :)]? Is there any possibility to have benefits of these two data structures in a single list? I guess, data structure designers must have thought about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712952/is-there-a-known-implementation-of-an-indexed-linked-list

Comment: You said it yourself, if there was a non-compromise solution that had all those benefits, nobody would even know about `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

Comment: @Aubin thanks for the link. +1 :)
but its a 2009 question. Any improvements in the field of Data structures in the past 3 years? Especially after the release of Java 7?

Comment: The well known containers algorithms are not recently discovered...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So what I have mentioned in point 3 is correct? Currently we do not have any data structure which is as fast as Arraylist regarding iteration and as fast as Linkedlist regarding insertion/deletion?

Comment: @Aubin Please share some useful info like Trimble did by sharing about FastList and FastTable

Comment: You have mentioned just two requirements (performance-related). Those two could possibly be matched, but **not** together with space efficiency of the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for some more performant collection implementations, check out [Javolution](http://javolution.org).  That package provides a [FastList](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastList.html) and [FastTable](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastTable.html) which may at least reduce the cost of choosing between linked lists and array lists.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Clojure's "vectors" (which are a lot more than a simple array under the hood): http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/02/01/understanding-clojures-persistentvector-implementation/. They are O(log32 n) for lookup and insertion.

Note that these are directly usable from Java! (Actually, they're implemented in Java code.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably we have another points to consider, but one aspect that make me choose [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) over [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is when:

- When I don't need to get an element by index (in case of process all elements)
- When I don't know the size when creating my list

Here is an interesting [manifesto](https://manifesto.co.uk/java-lists-arraylist-vs-linkedlist/) about this topic.

Comment: Even then, using an array list will likely perform better than a linked list (and use less memory).

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel,

You are right, here is a very interesting discussion about this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564352/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-from-memory-allocation-perspective