# Why is accessing an item by index slower in a linked list than an array?

Tags: java

I think I am missing a very obvious point but could not find it in my Java textbook.

I understand that node storage does not necessarily have to be contiguous in memory for linked list. Does this also mean that a linked list is not indexable? If so, then the only way to find an item in a linked list is to traverse the list, right, whereas you can `get` from an array by index?

Comment: Linked list access is (sequential, so) O(n); array access is (random, so) O(1).  There's a lot of good information in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: Thank you @BrianSnow. I am still not understanding why a linked list is not indexable. From what I've gathered, does a linked list not hold a reference to all the items it holds - only the head and/or tail? Thus not allowing access by index?

Comment: Let's say you have a linked list named L.  Potentially, the only operation exposed on L will be `head()`, which returns the head of the list: `Node<T> head = L.head()`.  The head of the list is simply a node, which also only exposes one operation, called `next()`, which returns the next node in the list.  You can now iterate through the list by doing `Node<T> node = head.next()` until you hit the end of the list and `node.next() == null`.  So you are correct: a linked list does not keep direct references to all of its elements -- it only keeps a reference to its head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is accessing an item by index slower in a linked list than an array?

A linked list has a chain of entries.  If you want to get (say) the element at position `42`, the code has to:

- get the entry for the first element (position `0`)
- follow the `next` link to the entry for position `1`
- follow the `next` link to the entry for position `2`

and so on .... 42 times in total.

There is no short cut.

> I am still not understanding why a linked list is not indexable ....

Now a `LinkedList` is indexable in the sense that there is a `get(int)` operation *that works*.  It is just that indexing a `LinkedList` is *inefficient*.  In general, it takes `O(N)` steps to perform a `get(i)` in a linked list of length `N`.  By contrast with an array, or an `ArrayList`, you can retrieve any element of the data structure in one step.  We say that the complexity is `O(1)`.

Contrast this with `Set` objects in general, and `HashSet` in particular.  The `HashSet` class is NOT indexable because there is no `get(int)` method to retrieve the set element at position `i`.  Indeed, even the notion of "position i" in a set is meaningless.  The ordering of the elements in a `Set` is unspecified and (for some `Set` implementations, like `HashSet`) it may be effectively indeterminate.

Comment: Again, my question is, can we use the index with linked lists?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from doing that.  Apart from the fact that it will be *slow*.   Besides, I already answered that: *"LinkedList is indexable in the sense that there is a get(int) operation that works."*

Answer (score 1):

Some Linked list implementations provide a way to access to it's elements using index, but the fact is that if you want to get 10th element in linked list your compiler still has to go through all the sequence from 0 to 9 because the elements may be spread over the memory. On the other hand when you ask for 10th element in an array using index, compiler computes the exact position of 10th element and jumps directly to that element. Array and list have different purposes; if your algorithm requires go back and forward over your data structure, then it is much efficient to use array. If you need mostly add/remove operations, then it is efficient to use list

Answer (score 0):

With a  linked list you can add and remove elements at any time so index it has no sense. Imagine that you create an index that points at the third element of the list. After that, you insert a new element at the beginning of the list. What value should return the index?

However it could be possible for example create an index at the middle of the list and use it only if you add o remove elements in the last half of the list.

@paxdiablo explains it very well here [Is there a known implementation of an indexed linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712952/is-there-a-known-implementation-of-an-indexed-linked-list)

Comment: The 2-D linked list implementation that @paxdiablo presented is `O(N^0.5)`.  It is interesting, but of limited *practical* use ... as a general list structure in Java.  Considering that `ArrayList` is `O(1)` and that it uses *less* space than any general purpose linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in memory allocation. The ArrayList will have a contiguous block of memory. So accessing elements will happen in constant time. Since knowing memory location of one element, address of nth element can be calculated(n*size of data type). So no need to transverse through all elements. But that is not case of LinkedList, there is no contiguous block. Only way to reach nth element is through transversing through elements.