# What is the difference between a indexed linked list and a array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I am confused because both of these contain an index, so a indexed linked list has nodes and indexes? While array list only has indexes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: I looked at that link, and it only talks about linked lists in general...but what about specifically a indexed linked list?

Comment: where did you find such a data structure in the first place?

Comment: Related: [Is there a known implementation of an indexed linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712952/is-there-a-known-implementation-of-an-indexed-linked-list)

Comment: What do you mean by an "indexed linked list"?  Are you asking specifically about `java.util.LinkedList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is continuous representation of the data .

So if base addr is lets say 64 and you want a element at 4th index and size of each element is 4 bytes so by doing the math we can say at what memory addr to look for 4th index element . So we can land at up at the element directly

On the other hand Linked List we have to traverse node by node and by counting the numbers of node traversed .

SO index works for both of them.For arraylist we can access it directly but in Linked list we have to traverse the intermediate nodes