# Can be linked-list indexable in c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I know a node-list bound by pointers cannot be indexed as array -> `[]` operator (as start pointer `*p + n` index to get to element at that index). And speaking about `[]` operator, such as `*(start+n)` which is pointer addition, not numeric addition. The real number which will be added to `start` pointer depends on the type, specifically on `sizeof(T)` of that type. So if `sizeof(int)==4` and having `int *p` starting at `0xa`, then `p+2` gives address `0x12` and not `0xc`. This just for clarity.

So having this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int v;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t *head){
    for(node_t*i=head;i;i=i->next)
        printf("%i\n",i->v);
}

node_t *push_back(node_t **head,int v){
    node_t *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    tmp->v=v;
    tmp->next=*head;
    *head=tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int size(node_t *head){
    int size=0; 
    for(node_t *i=head;i;i=i->next)
        size++;
    return size;
}


int main(){
    node_t *head = 0;
    for(int i =1; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        push_back(&head, i);
    }
    int s = size(head);

    printf("sizeof(node_t) is %li\n",sizeof(node_t));   
    printf("number of elements (without header) is %i\n",size(head));
    printf("%i\n",head[9-s].v); //or *head
    printf("%i\n",head[7-s].v); //or head[-2]
    printf("%i\n",head[5-s].v); //or head[-4]
    printf("%i\n",head[3-s].v); //...
    printf("%i\n",head[1-s].v);
    printf("%i\n",head[-1-s].v);
    printf("%i\n",head[-3-s].v);
    // ...
}
```

*OUTPUT*:

```
sizeof(node_t) is 16
number of elements (without header) is 9
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
```

1. How is even possible I can index node-list structure, when each of the elements should **not** be sequential, because they got their uniq address from `malloc` (in `create`) and thus should be scattered in memory
2. If I concede the elements are *sequential* from the start-point `head`, then why can I access them over 2 indexes, instead of 1? I am not moving 2 bytes, but 2 elements, and as from output, the `sizeof(node_t)` is 16, so I am moving 32 bytes back. But from output is seen I am in fact going one-element back, why?
3. Does operator `+` behave as pointer addition only in pointer context? And in any other context, it is just plain "arithmetic" operator? In what context is my case then?

Comment: At first glance I think this is a lot of undefined behaviour, it just coincidentally works. `head` is a single pointer, it is *not* an array, though C will gladly let you try and use it as one if you don't care about the consequences. Perhaps the `malloc` calls are handing over sequential chunks of memory in this case, but that behaviour is not in any way guaranteed.

Comment: Here is a [post on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712952/is-there-a-known-implementation-of-an-indexed-linked-list) (but more theoretical)

Comment: I think the oddness with +2 instead of +1 comes about from the size vs. alignment of your structure. I think you'd get different behaviour on 64-bit vs. 32-bit.

Comment: @tadman this is no coincidend, if that would occure only for first 2 elements... but for **every** of them? No I *can* clearly index linked-list via `head` pointer

Comment: @ryyker thanks for that though

Comment: You have a 12 byte structure (64-bit) with an 8 byte alignment requirement. They can't pack end-to-end, there has to be a gap.

Comment: 1. Indexing the list or playing Russian Roulette -- you have the same odds of winning. 2. Do NOT concede point 2 -- you were correct to begin with, subsequent returns by `malloc` are in no way guaranteed sequential. An array is the only thing that guarantees sequential elements. 3. the pointer **type** controls pointer arithmetic. `char *p` and then `p + 1` advances 1-byte in memory to the next `char`. `int *p` and then `p + 1` advances 4-bytes in memory to the next `int`.

Comment: The term _indexable_ is not synonymous with _sequential memory locations_.  Yes.  There are ways to do this.  ( eg. Include in `int` member of your list struct called index which is assigned at creation, then sort or search on that index.)

Comment: @milanHrabos: you need to try to avoid jumping to conclusions from small patterns, both in computing and in life in general. In this case, you're examining the behaviour of malloc on a small number of identically-sized requests at program startup, probably before any allocated block has been returned with a call to free(). Under those idiosyncratic circumstances, some regularity is to be expected. But to assume that this regularity is a necessary characteristic is a catastrophic error. Try this experiment after a lot of blocks have been allocated and some of them have been freed . For example.

Comment: You might find it useful to read the extremely simplified implementation of malloc and free in K&R, or some other programming textbook.